# Developing Emoji Component

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, emoji

I am developing the emoji component with javascript, but I am not using the react framework. Is there a single list with unicodes of all emojis? I can display an emoji on the screen using Emoji unicode(eg & # 128517). But how do I turn them into buttons. I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap your unicode in a button element like this. is this what you wanted to achieve? a full list of available unicodes and their supported platforms can be found here: https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

```html
<button> &#128540;</button>
```

Comment: yes i know here but i am looking for data in .json or xml format all. It is very troublesome and unreasonable to make copy and paste with one hand. Thank you for your answer separately.

Comment: Something like this? https://unpkg.com/emoji.json@12.1.1/emoji.json